# Convertir Object a string

Tags: json, .net, conversión-de-tipos, maui

en C# .Net 7 MAUI, tengo una consulta desde la base de datos y este es mi converter para llevar la imagen del Json a ImageSource. pero al momento de yo castear la variable de tipo object value me saltan errores de casteo este es mi código original:

´´public class ConvertImageSource : IValueConverter
{

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    string Valor = (string)value;
    byte[] buffer = System.Convert.FromBase64String(Valor);
    return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(buffer));
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

}
´´

cuando realizo el cast recivo el siguente error:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

aclaro que ese converter lo voy a usar para mostrar imagenes en .net MAUI que consulto de PostgresSQL 9.1, aunque eso no es lo que esta mal porque hice una prueba colocando el string directo que recibo del Json y este realiza la conversión de manera correcta y me muestra exitosamente la imagen deseada, el problema esta en que no puedo castear la variable de manera correcta y por ende el proceso queda incompleto.

si la casteo de la siguiente forma me salta otro error:
string ValorBase64 = value as string;

me sale este error en la siguiente linea de codigo porque la string no termina siendo nula haun cuando en value si hay valores
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')'

y si la casteo de esta ultima forma me salta el siguiente error:
string ValorBase64 = value.ToString();

System.FormatException: 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.'

Comment: pero esta viniendo un valor?? porque el segundo error dice que es null...

Comment: si estoy recibiendo un valor, lo comprove con los Ends Points de Visual Studio, solo que en el segundo caso la conversion da como resultado un null

Comment: agregate un try catch que verifique que no sea null el valor...

Comment: ya lo hice tambien, la variable value tiene valores

Comment: Y de que tipo es, se puede convertir a string?

Comment: tengo entendido de que se puede, en la pregunta esta especificado, estoy recibiendo una imagen desde la base de datos a través de el json ósea una cadena base64 y este tengo entendido que se puede convertir.

Comment: Si ese código te ha funcionado colocando el JSON directamente es que entonces el código que has puesto es correcto y tu problema está antes.

Comment: Bueno como podría entonces realizar este proceso de conversión en .Net MAUI?

Comment: Algo no esta llegando bien a este punto.. no a un punto anterior, a este punto.. si no activaste un log, es hora que lo hagas para que puedas ver que tipo de objeto llega a este punto y si llega bien.. si decis que lo hiciste a mano y anduvo, como te dijeron antes, entonces el problema no es este metodo, si no lo que recibe...

Comment: Agrega `var tipo = value.GetType();` y luego un punto de interrupción abajo de esa linea y luego cuéntanos que tipo de dato es el que está entrando (el valor de la variable llamada `tipo`).